# Problem with type ORM query builder. How to prepare query?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

I want to get data from db in special format. Below my entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Set {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;
  @OneToMany(() => Access, (access) => access.set, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  access: Access;

  @OneToMany(() => Word, (word) => word.set)
  word: Word;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Access {
  @Exclude()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('enum', {
    enum: Role,
    default: Role.Owner,
  })
  role: Role;
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.access, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
  @ManyToOne(() => Set, (set) => set.access, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  set: Set;
}
```

There is my query function:

```
    const sourceQuery = await this.setsRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('set')
      .leftJoinAndMapOne(
        'set.access',
        Access,
        'access',
        'access.setId = set.id',
      )
      .where('access.userId = 1')
      .getMany();
```

With this query I get that in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "first setterino",
        "access": {
            "role": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "first setterino",
        "access": {
            "role": 1
        }
    }
]
```

My goal is to achive this, without format function (only query):

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "first setterino",
        "role": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "first setterino",
        "role": 1
    }
]
```

I tried to use use inner join but it didnt help. Furthermore I have to use .getMany() at the end because of Serializer Options